# How can I create this XML using DOM Parser in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

How can I create this XML using DOM Parser in PHP?

```
<dict>
   <key>CGBlendMode</key>
   <integer>1000</integer>
   <key>backgroundColorRGBA</key>
   <string>RGBA:0.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000</string>
   <key>cornerRadius</key>
   <real>5</real>
</dict>
```

Comment: The question is not readable in it's [current version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21812410/3). To format code, select the code, and press Ctrl + K (or the `{}` button in the editing toolbox).

Answer (score 2):

You should use PHP DOMDocument Object

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$element = $dom->createElement('test', 'This is the root element!');
// We insert the new element as root (child of the document)
$dom->appendChild($element);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

give output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>This is the root element!</test>
```

here you can read more about DOMDocument:

```
 http://www.php.net/manual/pl/class.domdocument.php
```

Comment: You linked to the Polish translation, English would be http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php